# making a barchar using R / R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

The code I wrote in the r setup section in r markdown was,

```
roaddataSet <- read.csv("https://bitre.gov.au/statistics/safety/files/Fatalities_June_2017.csv")
data <- select(roaddataSet, Year, State)
```

(this was to extract certain columns from the data set)

then for the barchart, I wrote,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=State, y=Year)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
       labs(x="State", y="Year")
```

this runs the program successfully, however, the y-axis shown in the barchart diagram(not the title for ylab!) is written as some strange words such as "1e + 07"... not showing the numbers for "Year" which should be from 1989 to 2017. The x-axis is fine, it displays the names for each states

Is there anyway to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: You could try `as.factor(Year)`

Comment: you mean, instead of just putting y= Year?

Comment: I tried y = as.factor(Year), but it does not work ;(

Comment: Why are you plotting a barchart of two categorical variables? - What are you expecting to see?

Comment: In the csv file above, there are many columns / data sets, and I want to make a barchart that shows Australian road fatalities state vs year...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you're after:

```
data$Year<-as.factor(data$Year)

p <- ggplot(data)
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y = ..count.., fill= State))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete("Year", breaks=levels(data$Year))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))

p
```

Here, `..count..` is the count of each `State` per `Year`, which is then plotted against `Year`, and coloured by `State`

[image]

Comment: As a final question, can you please tell me how to make boxplot with gender vs year (year is from 2010 to 2017)?? I feel really sorry for asking this but I really need help.. Sorry

Comment: @seung - You're welcome. You should ask a new question re: your second comment - and remember to make it clear what you've tried, what your output is and how it's different from what you want/expect.

Answer (score -1):

The bar chart accumulates the year (interpreted as a number)...:

```
    sum(data$Year[data$State=="NSW"])
```

yields a result of 29816081 which is approx 3e7 which is what you have in the graph for NSW.   Maybe you start out by specifying what exactly you want to display in the bar chart.

Comment: Ah, then if I do like, height = c(1989... 2017), then do I just replace the y = Year as y = height?